# How to grep a continuous stream from the CLI and exit if string found

Tags: grep

I need to grep a continuous output stream from a ping-type output and check for the pattern "EOF" then quit if found.  So far I have used the line buffering mode in grep and also have tried to output to a file, grep the file, but have not been able to get this to work.  Last resort is to ask the community for help.  Ideally I don't want a debug file and just want to have the code execute through pipes and if then statements.
"Apt-get install hping3" will get the hping3 package.

My current output is a endless stream of "EOF reached, wait some second than press ctrl+c" which is why I am trying to write to script to exit the loop on it's own instead of having to monitor the loop to press ctrl-c.

```
    #$1 - destination IP
    #$2 - signature
    #$3 - filename
    #$4 - data frame size
    CMD="hping3 $1 --icmp --sign $2 --file $3 -d $4 -u"
    EXP="EOF"
    while true
        do
        $CMD | grep -q --line-buffered -m 1 $EXP > ./debug.txt
            if grep "$EXP" ./debug.txt
            then
            echo "string found"
            fi
    exit
    done
```

Comment: Why do you have a `while` loop with an `exit` in it? [Don't put commands in strings](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). What about `hping3 ... | grep -q -m 1 --line-buffered EOF` doesn't work exactly?

Comment: "hping3 10.0.2.2 --icmp --sign exfil-lab --file test.txt -d 50 -u | grep -q -m 1 --line-buffered EOF"   prints the same stream.  But couldnt that also be because grep found the pattern 'EOF' and is printing that line?  That's why I thought my problem had to be with the validation statement.  

Thanks for the link, very informative,  but I need to find a way to stop the next iteration of hping3 from occurring so I'm all ears.

Comment: Does `hping3` send to standard output or standard error? `grep -q` shouldn't output anything and should quit on the first match. Does `hping3 ... 2>&1 | grep -q ...` work the way you want?

Comment: "if hping3 $1 --icmp --sign $2 --file $3 -d $4 -u 2>&1 | grep -q --line-buffered -m 1 EOF" works perfectly.  I guess I need to research the difference between standard out vs error in case (when) I run into this again.  Thanks!

Comment: The main clue should have been that you were seeing the `hping3` output on screen and not in the `debug.txt` file. That meant that neither `grep` nor the redirection was seeing it at all. Which means it wasn't standard output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
hping3 $1 --icmp --sign $2 --file $3 -d $4 -u | sed '/EOF/q0'
```

What this does is that it will continually tail your log file and send the output to sed. Sed will search for the regex that you specify (you could add `^` if `EOF` is at the start of the line) and then exit with a code of 0 (the `q0` sed command). You may use whatever exit code you prefer after the `q` command.